# Bluetooth not recognized in debian testing

Tags: linux, debian, drivers, bluetooth, bluez

After performing a clean install of debian testing, installing the proprietary firmware, everything works fine, except bluetooth.
This seems to be recognized only by lsusb:

```
lsusb | grep Blue
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. AX201 Bluetooth
```

while the lsmod command:

```
lsmod | grep "blue"
bluetooth             954368  15 btrtl,btmtk,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb
ecdh_generic           16384  1 bluetooth
rfkill                 32768  9 iwlmvm,bluetooth,cfg80211
crc16                  16384  2 bluetooth,ext4
```

But `hcitool dev` also doesn't find any devices.
Now when I try to use bluetoothctl power on:

```
No default controller available
```

I tried several times to restart the bluetooth service, but nothing changed.
This is the status:

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2022-11-28 16:45:52 CET; 32min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 2055 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 18760)
     Memory: 2.1M
        CPU: 17ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─2055 /usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd

nov 28 16:45:51 MsiPulse bluetoothd[2055]: src/main.c:btd_parse_kernel_experimental() Invalid KernelExperimental UUID: false
nov 28 16:45:51 MsiPulse bluetoothd[2055]: Starting SDP server
nov 28 16:45:51 MsiPulse bluetoothd[2055]: profiles/audio/vcp.c:vcp_init() D-Bus experimental not enabled
nov 28 16:45:51 MsiPulse bluetoothd[2055]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() Failed to init vcp plugin
nov 28 16:45:51 MsiPulse bluetoothd[2055]: profiles/audio/mcp.c:mcp_init() D-Bus experimental not enabled
nov 28 16:45:51 MsiPulse bluetoothd[2055]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() Failed to init mcp plugin
nov 28 16:45:51 MsiPulse bluetoothd[2055]: profiles/audio/bap.c:bap_init() D-Bus experimental not enabled
nov 28 16:45:51 MsiPulse bluetoothd[2055]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() Failed to init bap plugin
nov 28 16:45:51 MsiPulse bluetoothd[2055]: Bluetooth management interface 1.22 initialized
nov 28 16:45:52 MsiPulse systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
```

The last thing I tried, following this last error is to try to enable experimental d-bus by uncommenting `#Experimental = true` and `#KernelExperimental = true` in the /etc/bluetooth/main.conf file, but all the same nothing has changed.

Ps I already installed firmware-linux-nonfree and firmware-iwlwifi.

Comment: I'd start by looking into those error messages...

Answer (score 1):

If it can be useful to anyone, apparently it's a missing driver, because dmesg clearly says:

`[ 5.655154] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to load Intel firmware file intel/ibt-0040-4150.sfi (-2)`

Now, I could download the driver by hand and put it in the appropriate folder, as described in this post https://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?p=762651, but I prefer to wait for the linux-firmware package present in the repo to be updated. I saw that debian sid already has the latest version, so it's a matter of days.